# Monterey update fails against APFS volume because "it cannot be converted to Apple File System (APFS)"

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, software-update, monterey

Attempting to update macOS Catalina 10.15.7 to Monterey on 16" Macbook Pro (late 2019) via Software Update fails because "disk2s2 is not convertible to APFS: You may not install to this volume because it cannot be converted to Apple File System (APFS)."

Installer Logs show:

```
Jan 20 11:06:45 petrus-mbp16 osinstallersetupd[99866]: ensurePrebootVolumeForDisk: EnsureRecoveryBooter: APFS Recovery Volume recoveryVolumePreExisted=1
Jan 20 11:06:46 petrus-mbp16 InstallAssistant[99862]: OSISClient: Interrupted!
Jan 20 11:06:49 petrus-mbp16 osinstallersetupd[10341]: osinstallersetupd registered client
Jan 20 11:06:49 petrus-mbp16 osinstallersetupd[10341]: disk2s2 is not convertible to APFS: You may not install to this volume because it cannot be converted to Apple File System (APFS).
```

Disk Utility shows all my drives are already APFS volumes. Hmm, `disk2s2`? That's the "Shared Support" drive that the updater downloaded...

[image: /Volumes/Shared Support is Mac OS Extended]

Attempting to convert this drive to APFS manually fails with "internal error".

How do I update my macOS given that the official update fails?

[image: failed macOS Monterey update]

Comment: Restart the Mac, download macOS Monterey from the App Store, then use the downloaded "Install macOS Monterey" application to install Monterey.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidAnderson. I managed to update. If you post your comment as an answer, I will mark it as accepted. Funny, I had the installer downloaded and it didn't work when I downloaded it. But when I tried it now, it updated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restart the Mac, download macOS Monterey from the App Store, then use the downloaded "Install macOS Monterey" application to install Monterey.

Comment: Furthermore, if you download the installer from the AppStore, you can create a bootable USB drive using [Apple's documenation here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372). This would give you access to Disk Utility and the terminal, both with the ability to completely erase the disk, repartition as the desired format, and then perform the installation. Although, this is a more destructive form of solving your problem. Make sure you have a backup and that your backups are working as expected.